# I'm getting a CORS error although Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is not set

Tags: node.js, heroku, http-post, cors

I wrote a server app with node.js and express. The app uses the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) node package for POST requests with origin `"*"` because I need to be able to post from mobile apps.

Here is how CORS is enabled in the app:

```
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
  app.use(cors());
});
```

When I try to POST a request from a browser, I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load *url*. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

However, I don't see any Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header in the response. Here is the failing request and the response in Chrome's network tab:

[image]

Why does it complain about the `credentials` flag?

Comment: Could you show us how do you enable and configure CORS in your app?

Comment: I added a code snippet.

Comment: Be aware that `app.configure` is removed in Express 4.x https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally solved this. Here are our findings and the train of thought that led us to the solution:

- The CORS issue happened only with POST, not GET.
- The CORS issue happened only when I made the request from a local HTML whose URL starts with `file://`. There was no issue when I requested it from `http://localhost`.
- When initiating a POST request from the `file://` protocol, the origin is `null`. Turns out that the issue was that `null` is not covered by the wildcard `*`.
- Setting `Allow-Access-Control-Origin` to `null` was not enough, because apparently a request from origin `null` includes credentials, so I had to set `Allow-Access-Control-Credentials` to `true`.

So here is my updated server code that accepts POST requests from any source, including a web view in a mobile app that works with `file://`:

```
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
  app.use(cors({ origin: 'null', credentials: true }));
});
```